# Universal Links on iOS weird behavior

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, ios-universal-links

I have configured Universal Links on iOS, and they're working everywhere on the XCode Simulator. Now when I test my app on an actual device, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. If I open the Notes app and create a new note with my domain URL, I long tap on it, and the menu that opens up has `Open in [App]` in it, and if I tap on it my `[App]` is opened. When testing out an oauth flow that redirects to my domain's URL, however, I'm taken to the website in the `SFAuthenticationSession` instead of back to the app. It's a standalone app built using `Expo SDKV37`. Anyone had this happen to them in the past? Any way to debug/resolve?

Comment: So you're saying that same flow works on simulator but not on phone?

Comment: @matt exactly yes! it's pretty weird